# How can I implement react-markdown within a react-table cell?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-markdown

In the app I am currently working on, there is a "Description" column which I would like to have rich text. This would be stored in my database in Markdown format. Is there anyway when using react-table to have cells contain content in another component, in this case so the content could be rendered by react-markdown?

Before implementing react-table I was able to parse the markdown in the description cells with `<td><ReactMarkdown>{item.description}</ReactMarkdown></td>`, but I'm not seeing a way to accomplish this with react-table.

This is the code in question: https://github.com/TechValleyCenterOfGravity/STUFF/blob/main/src/App.js

Comment: I was able to figure out the the [column options](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#column-options) and added the following ```cell: props => <ReactMarkdown>{ props.value }</ReactMarkdown>```, unfortunately the markdown is still not being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I missed a capital C - `Cell: props => <ReactMarkdown>{ props.value }</ReactMarkdown>` did the trick